# Python why is this invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm fairly new to python and I have received an invalid syntax error.

`res = (True in (!(((point[0] > (p[0] - 5)) and (point[0] < (p[0] + 5))) and ((point[1] > (p[1] - 5)) and (point[1] < (p[1] + 5)))) for p in pointsClicked))`

I've looked at this for a bit and have no idea what is causing the problem.

Comment: Note, the error message points directly at the "!" problem.

Comment: The error message has a `^` pointing to the `!` character, which should have been a big clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have a `!` operator. Use the `not` operator instead.